# ansible rolling restart playboook

Tags: ansible

Folks,
  I'd like to have a service be restarted individually on each host, and wait for user input before continuing onto the next host in the inventory.

Currently, if you have the following:

```
- name: Restart something
  command: service foo restart
  tags:
    - foo
- name: wait
  pause: prompt="Make sure org.foo.FooOverload exception is not present"
  tags:
    - foo
```

It will only prompt once, and not really have the effect desired.

What is the proper ansible syntax to wait for user input before running the restart task on each host?

Answer (score 5):

Use a combination of `serial` attribute and `step` option of a playbook.

playbook.yml

```
- name: Do it
  hosts: myhosts
  serial: 1

  tasks:
  - shell: hostname
```

Call the playbook with `--step` option

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --step
```

You will be prompted for every host.

```
    Perform task: shell hostname (y/n/c): y

    Perform task: shell hostname (y/n/c):  **************************************** 
    changed: [y.y.y.y]
    Perform task: shell hostname (y/n/c): y

    Perform task: shell hostname (y/n/c):  **************************************** 
    changed: [z.z.z.z]
```

For more information: [Start and Step](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_startnstep.html#step)

Comment: links for future reference : [playbooks delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html)  and [startnstep](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_startnstep.html#step)

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead with this:

```
- name: Restart Datastax Agent
  tags:
    - agent
  hosts: cassandra
  sudo: yes
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Pause
      pause: prompt="Hit RETURN to restart datastax agent on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    - name: Restarting Datastax Agent on {{ inventory_hostname }}
      service: name=datastax-agent state=restarted
```

Comment: Later if you decide to not pause between hosts, you have to edit your playbook. In my solution, don't specify the `--step` option.